# Relation between the time, velocity and acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, integration

This is question from I.E. Iredov's General Physics:

> *$1.22$ :  The velocity of a particle moving in the positive direction of the $x-axis$ varies as $v = α \sqrt x$, where $α$ is a positive constant. Assuming that at the moment $t = 0$ the particle was located at the point $x = 0$.*
>
> *(a) Find  the time dependence of the velocity and the acceleration of the particle.*

**My effort:**

$x=0 , t=0$

If I have $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\alpha \sqrt{x}$,

$\int_0^x\alpha \sqrt{x}$ gives the displacement. How would I possibly bring in the time $t$ in here.

Comment: Hi Inceptio. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Sorry. I wasn't aware of this. This is not the same as Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well integration is the basic method. But some observation can help too:

$$v=\alpha\sqrt x$$
$$\text{Squaring both sides:}$$
$$v^2=\alpha^2 x$$

We know $v^2\propto x$ gives constant acceleration.

$\text{Remember} :v^2=u^2+2as.$

So, comparing it with this equation we get $$v^2=0+2\frac{\alpha^2} 2 x$$

So, acceleration =$\alpha^2/2$ and velocity =$at=\alpha^2 t/2$

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $\dfrac{dx}{dt}= \alpha \sqrt{x}$ with respect to time again to get:

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \dfrac{\alpha}{2 \sqrt{x}} \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{\alpha}{2 \sqrt{x}} \alpha \sqrt{x} = \dfrac{\alpha ^2}{2}$$

Then:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{\alpha ^2 t}{2}$$

and:

$$x = \dfrac{(\alpha t)^2}{4} $$

for the given initial conditions.